# Open pin login page when app resume from pause for android device

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, crosswalk-runtime, ngcordova

In Angularjs app, I want when app will reopen after app pause (i.e. coming out of app by home button) it should open with pin login page. It should not resume app from where it was paused. To implement this I was tried the following code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

    document.addEventListener("pause", function(){
        var path = $location.path();
        if (path !== '/login') {
            $location.path('/login').replace();
            $rootScope.$apply();
        }
    });

}, false);
```

but this is not working for android devices because app is building over crosswalk plugin.

Please suggest some solution to resolve this.

Comment: change event listener from pause to resume. you want to perform action only during resume event.

Comment: https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/handling-apache-cordova-events-ionicframework/